# Data from array struct in corresponding shape

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, vectorization

Say, we have an array of structs

```
data = struct('position',[]);

data(1,1).position = 11;
data(1,2).position = 12;
data(2,1).position = 21;
data(2,2).position = 22;
```

I learned that to get the entries from a field from all structs in the array, we can use

```
>> [data.position]

ans =

    11    21    12    22
```

But this gives the data in a row. **How can we get it in the original shape of the array, without looping the array in MCode?**

Desired output:

```
position =

    11    12
    21    22
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html).  This will restructure an input vector / matrix into another vector / matrix of a desired shape.  Specifically, you can specify the dimensions of `data` into `reshape` as well as the row vector produced by `[data.position]` and it'll reshape the vector with the right dimensions for you.

```
data = struct('position',[]);

data(1,1).position = 11;
data(1,2).position = 12;
data(2,1).position = 21;
data(2,2).position = 22;

position = reshape([data.position], size(data))

position =

    11    12
    21    22
```

Note that the elements are shaped in column-major format so the values are stacked column-wise.  As you can see, the first two elements become the first column of the output matrix, while the last two elements become the second column of the output matrix.

Comment: Was to ask the same thing  `reshape([data.position], size(data))` _(may be shorter)_

Comment: @CitizenInsane - I was editing my answer while you placed that comment.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @CitizenInsane - Yup. This will certainly be shape agnostic.

Comment: Yeah, I wondered also how to deal with empty entries in the array, but thats another thing. Solution works fine.

Comment: If you have that situation that can't be done with reshape. One possible work around is to convert all elements into cells, then reshape that so that you get a 2D cell array. Btw glad it works!

Comment: @embert Haha that's what I started with actually using `struct2cell`. It's what @rayryeng just mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with empty entries, you can use `struct2cell` to convert the struct data into cell array that enables us to store empty entries as empty cells -

```
data_cell = permute(struct2cell(data),[2 3 1])

out  = data_cell(:,:,strcmp(fieldnames(data),'position'))
```

So, if you have something like this with the `(2,2)` missing -

```
data = struct('position',[]);
data(1,1).position = 11;
data(1,2).position = 12;
data(2,1).position = 21;
```

You would have -

```
out = 
    [11]    [12]
    [21]      []
```

---

Based on @CitizenInsane's nice observation and which might be very close to [`@rayryeng`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28669274/3293881), but one that deals with cell arrays instead of numeric arrays, would be this -

```
out = reshape({data.position}, size(data))
```

Comment: Why not just simply `reshape({data.position}, size(data))` _(i.e. just replaced `[]` with `{}`)_?

Comment: @CitizenInsane I think that would be pretty close to rayryeng's answer, so suggesting this as an alternative :) But that is a great idea really and compact one!!

Comment: Ah ok, thought you were just adressing for empty entries issue, sorry ;)

Comment: @CitizenInsane Well, added your idea! It should be a convenient one for OP! Thank you!